# "df.zoom To Selected Features ()" is not near enough

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.3

Excuse me for my bad english

I'm using ArcGIS 10.3 I am creating a script to screeshots

I'm using           df.zoomToSelectedFeatures ()

```
arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management ("Road", "NEW_SELECTION" '"dep" = 1')

df.zoomToSelectedFeatures ()

arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management ("Road", "CLEAR_SELECTION")

arcpy.mapping.ExportToJPEG (mxd, jpgfile1, df)
```

my problem is that the zoom is not enough

how to change my script, to Zoom more?

Comment: Have you tried multiplying your scale by a little bit?   **df.scale *= 1.1**

Comment: Errr... you want to zoom in more? Try dividing by a little bit.

Comment: as I can do so using the scale?

Comment: do your df.ZoomToSelectedFeatures(), then do the df.scale.

Answer (score 0):

As commented by @KHibma:

```
do your df.ZoomToSelectedFeatures(), then do the df.scale
```